# C# ASP.NET Web API 2 accept an array of ints as inparameter from AngularJS

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, arrays

I have the following code. Why can't I have an array or list as inparameter directly? It works fine with an array or list inside a class like below.

Request payload:

```
{"ids":[1,2,4]}
```

Angular:

```
send: {
    method: 'POST',
    url: controllerPath + '/send',
    isArray: true
}

agreementResource.send({ ids: vm.agreementIds }).$promise.then(function (data) {

});
```

C#:

```
//Works
[HttpPost]
[Route("send")]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public IHttpActionResult Send(AgreementIdsViewModel ids)
{
    foreach (var id in ids.Ids)
    {

    }
}


//Does not work
[HttpPost]
[Route("send")]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public IHttpActionResult Send(int[] ids)
{
    foreach (var id in ids)
    {

    }
}

public class AgreementIdsViewModel
{
    public int[] Ids { get; set; }
}
```

I know it can be done via GET-request so I think it should be possible.

```cs
GetSend([FromUri] int[] ids)
```

And send request:

```
/Send?ids=1&ids=2&ids=3
```

Comment: Use `public IHttpActionResult Send([FromBody] int[] ids)`

Comment: I agree with @Fabio and also you can set a break point inside your controller method and go through everything in this like the Request.Form.AllKeys

Comment: This did unfortunately not work

Answer (score 0):

please follow the following:

In angular service:

```
send: {
    method: 'POST',
    url: controllerPath + '/send',
   }
```

the big problem exists in your payload. it should look like the following:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

without adding ids. if you want to make it like this you can use lodash or underscore like the following:

```
 var ids = [];

 _.map(file, function (item, index) {
                ids.push(item.name);
            });
```

your Web Api doesn't have any problem, and it's correct:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("send")]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public IHttpActionResult Send(int[] ids)
{
    foreach (var id in ids)
    {

    }
}
```

and your angular controller where you will call the service looks like this:

```
agreementResource.send({ ids }).$promise.then(function (data) {}
```

Tell me if it is worked for you.

Comment: I don't want to add a library like `lodash` or `underscore` to make this work.

Comment: it is an important issue. it just to make it easy for you. The key point is that your payload should look like this: [1,2,3,4] and not like this {"ids":[1,2,4]}